# Having a problem with Python Request post library

Tags: python, request

i'm really struggling to understand what is the issue here... I'm new to python and all his library but i'm learning. I'm trying to learn the requests library for some future projects but i've encountered the following problem:

```
import requests
params = {'firstname': 'Test',  'lastname': 'Test'}
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post('http://pythonscraping.com/files/processing.php', data=params)
print(r.text)



Result: 
{'firstname': 'Test', 'lastname': 'Test'}
Hello there,  !
```

What i'm expecting to see is " Hello there, Test Test!"

I really don't understand what i'm doing wrong? Also i'm following a book that uses that site and teaches about the requests library but nothing is mentioned about this type of problem. Hopefully someone is able to help me out.

Comment: Reproduced but there is no way to know what the issue is without knowing the schema that the site expects and I cannot find this from the site itself. APIs are supposed to have documentation. So yea, don't use this site, it's badly made.

Comment: I even tried loading http://pythonscraping.com in a browser and it just hung. The site is probably not even being maintained anymore.

Comment: Sorry is this site not working for you?
http://pythonscraping.com/pages/files/form.html

Also when I navigate to pythonscraping.com it seems to be working for me?

Comment: I just use Postman in order to check your API and it seems that the server is the issue because even Postname cant get the response you are hoping for

Comment: The site works, and the example from the book (that uses `requests.post()`) works as well. The issue seems to be in regards to the `Session` class.

Comment: @OctaveL I've actually tried before without the Session object and I was having the same problem. That's why I tried with the Session class instead. Could it be something to do with my Python version and request library version? I'm currently using Python 3.8.6

Comment: @Reigin94 I was mistaken anyway, it has nothing to do with the `Session` class - the answer seems to be far simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with the URL `http://pythonscraping.com/pages/processing.php` (as opposed to yours, that fetches `/files/processing.php`), which is used in the book you're getting this example from.

Comment: Damn.. spent so much time for no reason on it.. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem, we all make mistakes! Remember to mark it as the answer to show the problem's been solved